# Реинициализация плагина jquery после появления элемента. Как?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть стандартные табы на jQuery.

```
$('ul.works-tab-link-list').on('click', 'li:not(.active)', function () {

$(this)
    .addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    .closest('.section-works').find('.works-tab__content-item').removeClass('active').eq($(this).index()).addClass('active');
```

});

Активный таб виден, остальные скрыты display:none. В табах есть плагин "до\после" для фотографий (cocoen). 
Так вот инициализация плагина действует только для первого видимого таба. Как инициализировать плагин на других табах? 
Была похожая ситуация с плагином slick, но у них есть отдельный метод который реинициализирует плагин.

Пробовал в html, в изначально скрытый таб, вставлять скрипт вот так (не работает).

```
<script>                                    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    $('.js-works-tab__content-ba-2').cocoen();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Вставлять скрипт бесполезно, потому что он отработает до того, как таб станет активным. Вам надо отлавливать событие переключения таба (активизации) и вот по этому событию каждый раз инициализировать Ваш cocoen.

Comment: Я пробовал в событие табов вставлять. Получается что при каждом клике идёт инициализация и задваивается плагин.

Comment: Без воспроизводимого примера, к сожалению, трудно сказать, что именно не так.